# Get image url using jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, src

How can i get the url of an image from "src =" within description tag

example :

```
 < description>&lt;div class="rss_thumbnail"&gt;&lt;img src="image url".......
```

Using Jsoup library
   My code :

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
            elements = doc.select("item");

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                FeedItem mItem = new FeedItem();
                mItem.setImageLink(elements.get(i).select("img").attr("src"));
                mItem.setTitle(elements.get(i).select("title").first().toString());
                mItem.setPubDate(elements.get(i).select("pubDate").first().text());
                mItem.setDescription(elements.get(i).select("description").first().text());
                mItem.setLink(elements.get(i).select("link").first().nextSibling().toString());
                feedItemList.add(mItem);}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is that I failed to get the url using the method above

Comment: Could you provide some bigger html, including the item tag. I don't care about the content of course, I just want the exact same html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the HTML, you can try to get the link by using

```
elements.get(i).select("img").first().attr("src")
```

Or

```
elements.get(i).select("a").first().attr("href")
```

You might have to play around with it for a while. Sometimes Jsoup doesn't cooperate well with links for whatever reason.

Comment: thank you , tried both but still wasn't able to get the url .